Scala spark subtract 2 rdd’s by a common field
I am new to scale and spark
need help in subtracting one rdd from another by ignoring a field
rdd1.take(2) 

/*
[{'uuid': 'uuid1',
  'Id ': 1,
  'Name': ‘jack’},
 {'uuid': 'uuid2',
  'Id': 0,
  'Name': ‘Jill’}]
*/

2nd RDD
rdd2.take(2)

/*
[{'uuid': 'uuid3',
  'Id ': 1,
  'Name': ‘jack’},
 {'uuid': 'uuid4',
  'Id': 0,
  'Name': ‘Jill’}]
*/

I want to subtract 2nd RDD from 1st by ignoring field uuid.
The result of rdd1.subtract(rdd2) should be empty
How can i achieve thus

Do you mean removing rows that are identical (ignoring the uuid column)?

If you don't care about the UUID in the end result, you could remove it from the RDD/DF and use except
